Laravel+FilamentPHP+Livewire on custom field, what goes where to handle 'state'?
I'm trying to figure out the layering withing Laravel using FilamentPHP and livewire components.
I need to have a clickable google maps for a Custom Field in filament php and I'm told that the best way to do this is via a livewire component.  I only need the javascript to load for this custom field so I thought this might be do-able using the alpine.js lazy-loading x-load-js functionality.
But now I have no clue how I'm supposed to handle the 'state' which is going to amount to an array with [ 'latitude' => float, 'longitude' => float ]
Following what examples I can find, I set up a custom field object:
namespace App\Filament\Forms\Components;

use Filament\Forms\Components\Field;

class GmapLocation extends Field
{

    protected string $view = 'filament.forms.components.gmap-location';

}

And a blade view for it:
<x-dynamic-component
    :component="$getFieldWrapperView()"
    :field="$field">

    @livewire('gmap-location', [
        // dunno if I need to pass state or statepath here??
    ])
</x-dynamic-component>

I then attempt to create a livewire component:
namespace App\Livewire;

use Livewire\Component;

class GmapLocation extends Component
{
    public function render()
    {
        return view('livewire.gmap-location');
    }
}


then the associated blade file for the livewire component that will actually handle loading the map javascript and rendering the clickable google maps.
<div
    x-data="{
            mapdiv: $refs.map,
        }"
    x-init="
        new Promise((resolve) => {
            // map code did not seem to be loading even with nextTick
            // so I added this to wait until the map class was defined
            // (I have another pending question on lazyloading in alpine)
            const checkCcrmap = () => {
                if (typeof(window.Ccrmap) === 'function') {
                    resolve();
                } else {
                    setTimeout(checkCcrmap, 100); // Check every 100ms
                }
            };
            checkCcrmap();
        }).then(() => {
            // define the map
            // *** the problem is that I don't know how to get the 'state' to this point ***
            // *** or if there is some other way I can retrieve it inside the gmap javascript ***
            window.ccrmapInstance = new window.Ccrmap(mapdiv, state);
            window.ccrmapInstance.initializeMap();
        });
        "
    x-load-js="[@js(\Filament\Support\Facades\FilamentAsset::getScriptSrc('gmap-location'))]"
    style="height: 600px; width: 400px;"
>
    <div x-ref="map" style="height: 100%; width: 100%;"></div>
</div>

What I basically need it to do is when the map is clicked, I have an event catcher for the click that creates (or relocates, if already created) an advanced marker on the google map.  If needed I can trigger a livewire event here to notify of the change of location, but I don't know how to access the state inside the component so ultimately laravel/filamentphp can know the state has been updated.
I've tried to get help in a couple places for filamentphp itself but their docs are wanting and their support forums seem to be hit or miss.  Any help getting this working is greatly appreciated!

Ultimately on the form I want to put this onto, there are also going to be text fields for latitude/longitude or uploading a kml waypoint file as options to enter a location. If either the map or the text fields are updated, i want them to be able to update the other. If a kml file is uploaded, I want both text fields and map updated.
